# How can my Android app open with one of two views, based on a condition?

Tags: android, view

This is my very first post on StackOverflow.

Basically, my app starts by checking to see if a user record exists in my Sqlite Database. If yes, I would like it to display my main application screen. If not, I would like another screen to be displayed, prompting the user for a password.

This password screen is a new addition to my app. It originally just displayed the main screen like so:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Then I would run the check for a user. If no user is found I display the password screen like so:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, loginScreenActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

The problem is, if I decide to hit the BACK button to exit out of the application from the password screen, it goes back to the main screen.

How can I first run the check, then display one of the two views??

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you navigate to the login screen, call finish() on the first screen

Comment: And then re-run the main screen activity with another intent after storing the password in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

read the [Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html) documentation, it will be very helpful.

You need to set the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP if you never wan1t go back to this screen.

Or the secont one, override the onbackpressed() method and use finish() method inside in.